# Search Missing Timestamp and display in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my some Dataset which having Time,Temperature1,Temperature2

```
Timestamp.             Temperature1.        Temperature2
09/01/2016 00:00:08          53.4.                       45.5
09/01/2016 00:00:38.         53.5.                       45.2
09/01/2016 00:01:08.         54.6.                        43.2
09/01/2016 00:01:38.         55.2.                        46.3
09/01/2016 00:02:08.         54.5.                        45.5
09/01/2016 00:04:08.         54.2.                       35.5
09/01/2016 00:05:08.         52.4.                        45.7
09/01/2016 00:05:38.         53.4.                         45.2
```

My data is coming in every 30 second..

This is my dataset here..some Timestamp is missing..bcoz. every 30 second my data is coming..so some data points are missing..
How to find that data points..and insert there data as NAN ...
Please help me..

Comment: can you post some code or tell us what you have tried?

Comment: You're looking for `resample`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-sampling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [resample('30S', base=8)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method:

```
In [20]: x.resample('30S', base=8).mean()
Out[20]:
                                 Temperature1    Temperature2
Timestamp
2016-09-01 00:00:08                      53.4            45.5
2016-09-01 00:00:38                      53.5            45.2
2016-09-01 00:01:08                      54.6            43.2
2016-09-01 00:01:38                      55.2            46.3
2016-09-01 00:02:08                      54.5            45.5
2016-09-01 00:02:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:08                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:04:08                      54.2            35.5
2016-09-01 00:04:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:05:08                      52.4            45.7
2016-09-01 00:05:38                      53.4            45.2
```

The solution above assumes that the `Timestamp` is of `datetime` dtype and that it has been set as index.
If `Timestamp` is a regular column (not index), then starting from Pandas 0.19.0 we can resample on regular columns (it must be of `datetime` dtype), using `on='column_name'` parameter:

```
In [26]: x.resample('30S', on='Timestamp', base=8).mean()
Out[26]:
                                 Temperature1    Temperature2
Timestamp
2016-09-01 00:00:08                      53.4            45.5
2016-09-01 00:00:38                      53.5            45.2
2016-09-01 00:01:08                      54.6            43.2
2016-09-01 00:01:38                      55.2            46.3
2016-09-01 00:02:08                      54.5            45.5
2016-09-01 00:02:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:08                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:04:08                      54.2            35.5
2016-09-01 00:04:38                       NaN             NaN
2016-09-01 00:05:08                      52.4            45.7
2016-09-01 00:05:38                      53.4            45.2
```

if you need to find your `base` value **dynamically** you can do it this way:

```
In [21]: x.index[0].second
Out[21]: 8
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> **base** : int, default 0
>
> For frequencies that evenly subdivide 1 day, the “origin” of the aggregated intervals. For example, for `5min` frequency, base could range from `0` through `4`.
>
> Defaults to `0`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the timestamps have been converted to `datetime`, if you set the index to the timestamp column and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a date range then the missing values will show up:

```
In [94]:
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
df

Out[94]:
                     Temperature1  Temperature2
Timestamp                                      
2016-09-01 00:00:08          53.4          45.5
2016-09-01 00:00:38          53.5          45.2
2016-09-01 00:01:08          54.6          43.2
2016-09-01 00:01:38          55.2          46.3
2016-09-01 00:02:08          54.5          45.5
2016-09-01 00:04:08          54.2          35.5
2016-09-01 00:05:08          52.4          45.7
2016-09-01 00:05:38          53.4          45.2

In [96]:    
df.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='30s'))

Out[96]:
                     Temperature1  Temperature2
2016-09-01 00:00:08          53.4          45.5
2016-09-01 00:00:38          53.5          45.2
2016-09-01 00:01:08          54.6          43.2
2016-09-01 00:01:38          55.2          46.3
2016-09-01 00:02:08          54.5          45.5
2016-09-01 00:02:38           NaN           NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:08           NaN           NaN
2016-09-01 00:03:38           NaN           NaN
2016-09-01 00:04:08          54.2          35.5
2016-09-01 00:04:38           NaN           NaN
2016-09-01 00:05:08          52.4          45.7
2016-09-01 00:05:38          53.4          45.2
```

This assumes that the timestamps are regular, here we construct a date range using the timestamp first and last values with a frequency of 30 seconds:

```
In [97]:
pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='30s')

Out[97]:
DatetimeIndex(['2016-09-01 00:00:08', '2016-09-01 00:00:38',
               '2016-09-01 00:01:08', '2016-09-01 00:01:38',
               '2016-09-01 00:02:08', '2016-09-01 00:02:38',
               '2016-09-01 00:03:08', '2016-09-01 00:03:38',
               '2016-09-01 00:04:08', '2016-09-01 00:04:38',
               '2016-09-01 00:05:08', '2016-09-01 00:05:38'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30S')
```

When you `reindex` with this, any missing index labels become `NaN` values

Comment: Thanks its really work...and if we are finding Avg so we can calculate Avg for missing data also..according to previous data ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? You want to fill in the missing values with the mean or you want mean to include the missing row values?

Comment: i want to calculate mean for missing value?

Comment: So you mean `df.mean(skipna=False)`?

Comment: one more question is arrive here i will post as a new question ..because some of my codes are not giving me proper output ..i am using linux.and same code is running properly in windows..

Comment: If we want to show which dated are missing without replacing with NaN only show missing value .how we can do.?

Comment: `pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='30s').difference(df.index)` should work after you;ve set the index to the timestamps

Comment: one more help.If i want to predict what will be future temperature for next 30 sec ?how can we predict using algorithm?which algorithm will suit?any suggestion ? i want to predict future temperature based  on future timestamp?