# How to search missing values from timestamp which are not in regular interval

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, missing-data

I have a dataset like this with data every 10 second interval.

```
  rec                   NO2_RAW  NO2    
0 2019-05-31 13:42:15   0.01    9.13    
1 2019-05-31 13:42:25   17.0     51.64  
2 2019-05-31 13:42:35   48.4    111.69
```

The timestamp is not consistent throughout the table. There are instances where after a long gap, the timestamp has started from a new time. Like after `2019-05-31 16:00:00`, it started from `2019-06-01 00:00:08`.

I want to `fill up the missing valu`e by calculating the `time difference` between two consecutive `rows (10s)` and assign `NAN` values to the missing time.

I saw this example [Search Missing Timestamp and display in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419060/search-missing-timestamp-and-display-in-python) but it is meant for consistent data. I want to calculate moving average of 15 minutes from this data. So I want a consistent data.
Can someone please help?

Comment: You will end with tons of rows filled with nan values. Are you ok with that? I don't know why you want that, but usually is not needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill in missing days in dataframe and add zero value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076342/fill-in-missing-days-in-dataframe-and-add-zero-value-in-python)

Comment: How do you intend to handle that the data will not be aligned to the same offset into 10 seconds? E.g. you go from vv:v5 to vv:v8. That is `10n + 3` seconds difference.

Comment: I want to do the moving average of the data. Is it okay to do it with data gap?