# Fill in missing days in dataframe and add zero value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
Date                      A          B
2014-12-20 00:00:00.000   3          2
2014-12-21 00:00:00.000   7          1
2014-12-22 00:00:00.000   2          9
2014-12-24 00:00:00.000   2          2
```

and I would like to add the missing day and fill the values for A and B with 0 so I get

```
Date                      A          B
2014-12-20 00:00:00.000   3          2
2014-12-21 00:00:00.000   7          1
2014-12-22 00:00:00.000   2          9
2014-12-23 00:00:00.000   0          0
2014-12-24 00:00:00.000   2          2
```

How is this achieved best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Date` is column create `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df1 = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
print (df1)
            A  B
Date            
2014-12-20  3  2
2014-12-21  7  1
2014-12-22  2  9
2014-12-23  0  0
2014-12-24  2  2
```

If first column is `index`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1 = df.asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
print (df1)
            A  B
Date            
2014-12-20  3  2
2014-12-21  7  1
2014-12-22  2  9
2014-12-23  0  0
2014-12-24  2  2
```