# Code to identify and write the missing timestamp for the missing hourly data in CSV with Python or R

Tags: python, r, timestamp

I have some experience using Python and R. The problem I am facing is that for the missing hourly data at the various stations, the timestamps are also missing. Due to the large size of the file (from 2017 to 2020), doing it manually would be very tedious. I am trying to write a code that will run through the CSV file, identify the missing time stamps for the missing data and insert the timestamps with NA or blank as the value. Can somebody help me with this? I have attached a sample picture of the original data and how I would want it to be. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnl4M.png)

Comment: You wrote that you are "trying to write code." Post it here so someone can help you debug it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to start writing the code for this issue. I have just managed to write a basic python code based on the pandas tutorial.

Comment: what do you mean by *missing data*? does it mean you have a time series with "gaps"? in principle, I'd suggest to load the `csv` into a `pandas.DataFrame`, do the processing and put back out to csv (or what ever you need). just google "read a csv file with pandas" to get started.

Comment: ...and as a hint, what you might want to look for is `resample` (to hourly frequency in your case), as e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419060/search-missing-timestamp-and-display-in-python).

Comment: yes. the time series has many data gaps. I have learnt how to load the csv into dataframe, but I don't know how to write a code to identify the missing timestamp and data in the time series and insert timestamp for the missing data.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try to use resample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can use `dplyr::complete()` for that purpose:

```
library(tidyverse) #includes dplyr

# generate dummy full dataset
full_data <- tibble(Date = as.Date(1:24),
              Hour = 1:24) %>%
  expand(Date, Hour) %>%
  mutate(Acc = rnorm(nrow(.)))
full_data
# A tibble: 576 x 3
#   Date        Hour     Acc
#   <date>     <int>   <dbl>
# 1 1970-01-02     1  0.453 
# 2 1970-01-02     2 -0.0518
# 3 1970-01-02     3  0.882 
# 4 1970-01-02     4 -0.386 
# 5 1970-01-02     5 -0.284 
# 6 1970-01-02     6  0.454 
# 7 1970-01-02     7 -0.754 
# 8 1970-01-02     8 -0.213 
# 9 1970-01-02     9  0.610 
# 10 1970-01-02    10  1.29  

# remove some timestamps that are missing
data_with_missing <- full_data %>%
  slice_sample(n=200)

data_with_missing 
# A tibble: 200 x 3
# Date        Hour      Acc
# <date>     <int>    <dbl>
#   1 1970-01-04     4  0.683  
# 2 1970-01-02     6  0.454  
# 3 1970-01-24    10 -1.67   
# 4 1970-01-12     6  1.12   
# 5 1970-01-13     5 -0.786  
# 6 1970-01-04     3 -2.03   
# 7 1970-01-11    22  1.02   
# 8 1970-01-11    15  1.11   
# 9 1970-01-18    22  0.688  
# 10 1970-01-24    14 -0.00612
# ... with 190 more rows

# Now use complete to fill in the missing data
recompleted_data <- data_with_missing %>%
  complete(Date, Hour)

recompleted_data 

# A tibble: 576 x 3
# Date        Hour    Acc
# <date>     <int>  <dbl>
#   1 1970-01-02     1 NA    
# 2 1970-01-02     2 NA    
# 3 1970-01-02     3 NA    
# 4 1970-01-02     4 -0.386
# 5 1970-01-02     5 -0.284
# 6 1970-01-02     6  0.454
# 7 1970-01-02     7 -0.754
# 8 1970-01-02     8 -0.213
# 9 1970-01-02     9 NA    
# 10 1970-01-02    10 NA    
# ... with 566 more rows

# Check that we have the same combinations as in the full dataset
all.equal(full_data[,1:2], recompleted_data[,1:2])
# TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Alexlok!

With the code, I could fill the missing hours in the dates that were listed originally. However, if the date is missing totally, the code couldn't detect the missing date and hour. Hence I have many gaps due to the missing dates. How can I modify the code such that I can detect the missing date too?

Comment: When defining the initial tibble, instead of `Date = as.Date(1:24)` in my example, you can use any specification that's practical for you. For example:
`beg <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
as.numeric(beg) # number of days since 1970-01-01
as.Date(beg:end, origin="1970-01-01")`